# Java comparator with relative distance

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, distance, comparator

I'm trying to create an ordered map which uses relative distance comparisons. However, the way ConcurrentSkipListMap(which is what I'm using at the moment) interprets comparisons from Comparator makes comparing relative distances impossible. Are there any data structures which allow for map like key-value operations and relative ordering?

When I say relative comparisons I mean that two values cannot be compared directly, but must be looked at with a reference point. Think like euclidian distance.

EDIT:

for example: when comparing the binary numbers 0011 and 1100 I want to say one is larger than the other based on Hamming distance (the number of 1 bits in the xor of two numbers, equivalently the distance between two nodes in a hypercube graph), obviously I need a reference point in order to compare distance, so I choose 0000 as a reference. The distance from 0011 to 0000 is 2, and the distance from 1100 to 0000 is 2, however 1100 is not equal to 0011. I would like to say that they have the same relative distance, but are not equal. Ultimately a sorted list of these numbers would be produced. For the reference 0000, in ascending order we might have 1000, 0100, 1100, 1001, 0011, 1110, 1101, 1111.

EDIT2, why I can't use a Comparator:

> The quotient for this total order is:
>          {(x, y) such that c.compare(x, y) == 0}.
>
> It follows immediately from the contract for compare that the quotient is an equivalence relation on S, and that the imposed ordering is a total order on S. When we say that the ordering imposed by c on S is consistent with equals, we mean that the quotient for the ordering is the equivalence relation defined by the objects' equals(Object) method(s):
>        {(x, y) such that x.equals(y)}.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Example input and output would be helpful.

Comment: Can you possibly post some code that shows what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't work? Or example inputs and outputs as khelwood said.

Comment: Why do you need to establish such ordering? Would a different data structure, e.g., a [4-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), work better for your purpose? If you are working with 4 dimensional geometry that might make more sense than a sorted list.

Comment: I'm not an expert on mathematical group theory. But my understanding of your quote is that the equivalence group for the comparator is defined by items that both result in 0 when the comparison is made. I can't see how that precludes using this type of comparator - as long as the behaviour of the comparator is fixed. In fact it is used often in coding so I suspect you are misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: *"I would like to say that they have the same relative distance, but are not equal."* Then you need to decide on some other metric to compare by too when their distance is equal.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I'm basically building an address table, I would like it to be sorted so that I can add new entries and easily remove the farthest entries to maintain a maximum size. I'm actually working in an arbitrarily large dimension, I just used 4 bits for simplicity.

Comment: Comparators are not *required* to be consistent with equals...

Comment: @Radiodef I had thought of doing that, but it would be a little hacky, I'm hoping there is some way to maintain the integrity of the comparator.

Comment: *"little hacky...maintain integrity"* To be honest I really have no idea what you're talking about. Multiple comparisons are so run-of-the-mill, [Comparator has a method built in just to do it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: You're probably right and I'll just do it. What I meant was that I don't want a DistanceComparator that falsely indicates that one point has a greater distance than another when that's not actually true. I'll probably just put a flag in the comparator class to enable or disable strict comparisons and toggle it when it matters.

Comment: What do you mean by address table? Can you add a link?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta the answer I marked will work for me. But if you're curious it's here https://github.com/blackdoor/DAC/blob/master/src/blackdoor/cqbe/addressing/AddressTable.java

The system is a distributed hash table with an overlay based on a hypercube, so the address table maps overlay addresses to layer 3 addresses and tries to keep only the nearest overlay addresses in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always distinguish instances that have the same distance to the reference number by doing further comparison when the distances are the same. For instance, assuming you represent your numbers as `Integer`s:

```
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        Integer r1 = hammingDistanceToReference(i1);
        Integer r2 = hammingDistanceToReference(i2);

        if (!r1.equals(r2))
            return r1.compareTo(r2);

        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
```

That way, numbers that have different Hamming distance to the reference will be ordered properly, and those that have the same Hamming distance will be also completely ordered.

Comment: I considered this approach, but I'd like to see if I can avoid it unless it's really needed.

Comment: Given that it's probably the cleanest and easiest approach, I'm not sure what you'd be avoiding exactly...

Comment: Also `Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount).thenComparing(Integer::compareTo)`.

Comment: Yes, Java 8 is fantastic... not familiar with it just yet (still stuck with Java 1.6 at work); but it would not really work in the current case where the basic comparator is parametrized by a reference number.

Comment: @FrédéricDumont I'd want to avoid having a distance comparator that indicates that one point is closer than another when that's not true. I'm just going to add a switch to enable or disable further comparisons so I can use them for sorting when I need to, or not when I need to know if the distances are really equal.

Answer (score -2):

Several of the `Set` implementations allow a comparator that is not consistent with equals. If `ConcurrentSkipListMap` does not then your options are to use one that does or to use an unordered collection and then sort it manually at insertion using `Collection.sort`.

Here is an example of creating a `Comparator` (inconsistent with equals):

```
class Point {
    int distanceTo(Point other) {
        ...
    }

    Comparator<Point> distanceComparator() {
        return (point1, point2) -> distanceTo(point1) - distanceTo(point2);
    }
}

List<Point> points;
Point fixedPoint;
Collections.sort(points, fixedPoints.distanceComparator());
```

This will now sort `points` by distance to `fixedPoint`. Alternatively, for efficiency reasons, you could use the fact that the set has already been sorted to insert at the correct position when you add new items:

You make reference to the documentation for `Comparator`, specifically the group theory definition of the relation. The key condition is that if two items are `equals` then they must return 0 when compared. However the opposite is certainly not the case: if two items return 0 when compared this does not necessarily imply that they are `equals`. There are many cases in which the order of two items is undefined. A simple example is dictionary ordering ignoring case. In this situation the words "Foobar", "foobar" and "FOOBAR" are all 'equal' with respect to the order.

This is referred to in the documentation as being 'inconsistent with respect to equals'. The documentation for `SortedSet` for example, says "The behavior of a sorted set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface." This is not true for all implementations of `Set`.

Comment: A comparator is what I had initially used, however as I mentioned the contract for comparator doesn't allow for this type of thing (in my case, trying to use a ConcurrentSkipListMap).

Comment: I'm not an expert on mathematical group theory. But my understanding of your quote is that the equivalence group for the comparator is defined by items that both result in 0 when the comparison is made. Or in my example, points that are equal distance from the fixed point. I can't see how that precludes using this type of comparator. In fact it is used often in  coding so I suspect you are misunderstanding the documentation.

Comment: I am also not an expert in group theory, but simply put compare(x,y) implies x.equals(y), if x is not in fact equal to y and I've got a map that doesn't allow duplicate keys, then I've got a problem.

Comment: @kag0 I assume you mean `compare(x, y) == 0` implies `x.equals(y)`? I disagree - I don't think it means that at all and I don't think you'll find that anywhere in the documentation. What is true is that `x.equals(y)` implies `compare(x,y) == 0`. But that's certainly true for the example I gave in my answer: the difference between the distance of a point to a fixed point with the distance of the same point to the same fixed point is 0.

Comment: @kag0 There's no mandate that a comparator must be consistent with equals. That's not part of the contract. It's a *recommendation* because Map and Set interface specifications are documented using equals. Read the doc again.

Comment: @sprinter yes that's what I meant, thank you. The documentation does say "It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y))" however ConcurrentSkipListMap does seem to take it as a given.

Comment: @kag0 ah ok now I understand. So it's really a question about how to use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` when the comparator is not consistent with equals.

Comment: @sprinter yes, or if there is another data structure that offers the same features I could use that instead.